# Why are Solr Filters disable bypassed when doing a fuzzy searches?

Tags: lucene, solr

My Solr setup contains the Filter LowerCaseFilterFactory for indexing and querying, so
- the index only contains lowercase words and
- every query is supposed to be turned lowercase before used for searching.

When doing a non-fuzzy search like "mix:barba", they are working fine:
- barba finds Barba and BARBA
- Barba finds Barba and BARBA

Problem is, as soon as I do fuzzy searches, those Filters seem bypassed:
- barba~0.8 finds Barba and BARBA
- Barba~0.8 finds nothing.

My interpretion of those results: when doing fuzzy searches, the query is not turned lowercase anymore (so already lowercase queries work fine because the index is also lowercase, but uppercase queries cannot match anything anymore).

How can I prevent fuzzy search from turning off LowerCaseFilterFactory?

Thanks!

schema.xml (shortened to the most relevant parts): http://pastie.org/853448

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look here. I had the same problem: [SOLR - wildcard search with capital letter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1840347/solr-wildcard-search-with-capital-letter)

Comment: Great, many thanks for the reply!

Though it's quite a bummer that I now have to implement this upstream...