# Solr Query with LIKE Clause

Tags: solr, lucene, solrnet, edismax

I'm working with Solr and I'd like to know if it is possible to have a LIKE clause in the query.  For example, I want to know all organizations with "New York" in the title.  In SQL, this would be written like Name LIKE 'New York%'.

My question - how do you write a LIKE query in Solr?

I'm using the SolrNet library, if that makes a difference.

Comment: you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088401/substring-matches-within-solr

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just search for "New York", but first you need to properly configure your field's analyzer. For example you might want to start with a field type like `text_general` as defined in the [default Solr schema](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/example/solr/conf/schema.xml?view=markup#l203). This field type will tokenize on whitespace and other common word separators, then apply a filter of stopwords, then lowercase the terms in order to make searches case-insensitive.

More information about [analyzers in the Solr wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters).

Comment: i have copy paste text_general from default collection1 schema.xml to my project but search didn't work. i am trying to search "hot" in string "is it hot in dubai?"

Comment: if i analyze it in Solr admin, it work there but if i search in Admin > Query it didn't

Answer (score 9):

If you're using solr 3.1 or newer, have a look at the [`Extended DisMax Query Parser`](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1553), which supports wildcard queries. You can enable it using `<str name="defType">edismax</str>` in the request handler configuration.

Then you can use a query like `title:New York*` with the same behaviour as a query with like clause. The main difference between my answer and the accepted one is that you can even search for fragment of words using wildcards. For example `New Yorkers` would match in this case.
Unfortunately you could have problems with case-sensitive queries even if you're using a `LowerCaseFilterFactory`. Have a look [here](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2011/11/29/whats-with-lowercasing-wildcard-multiterm-queries-in-solr/) to know more. Most of those problems will be fixed with the solr 3.6 release since the [SOLR-2438](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2438) issue has been solved.