# Sunspot `LIKE` query

Tags: ruby, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails, edismax

I'm using `sunspot`. How can I run a `LIKE` query (`LIKE %q%`)? I would like to do something like this:

```
 @search = Sunspot.search(User) do |q|
   q.text_fields { with(:company_name).like(params[:q]) }
 end.results
```

instead of:

```
@search = Sunspot.search(User) do |q|
  q.text_fields { with(:company_name).starting_with(params[:q]) }
end.results
```

which partially works for me. Reviewing the `sunspot` code, I found this piece of code:

```
class StartingWith < Base
  private

  def to_solr_conditional
    "#{solr_value(@value)}*"
  end
end
```

It basically generates the following sunspot search hash:

```
Sunspot.search(User) do |q| 
  q.text_fields { with(:company_name).starting_with("sta")} }
end

=> Sunspot::Search:{:q=>"*:*", :fq=>["type:User", "company_name_text:sta*"]}
```

In case there's no simpler way of implementing `LIKE %query%`, how should I create a new class `Like` with the method `to_solr_conditional` which generates the SOLR logic?

Comment: What do you mean by 'partially works for me'? :) In fact, the problem is that the search does not work, or you just want a method alias?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by 'no simpler way'? What can it be more simple than .starting_with('sta') ?

Comment: Hey Vlad, thanks for your answer, I'll explain in the following gist why it does partially work for me. https://gist.github.com/8257e7c4e512aa8a45df thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the standard DisMax handler, it does not support wildcards. You have 2 options:

a. Activate EdgeNGramFilter:

```
<fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer type="index">
    ..
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
    ..
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

b. Use nightly build Solr with [EDismax Handler](http://www.gettingahead.co.in/blogwp/2011/04/technical/shalini/some-new-features-update-in-solr-3-1/).

See [wiki article on sunspot docs](https://github.com/outoftime/sunspot/wiki/Wildcard-searching-with-ngrams) or [similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2413946/wildcard-searching-and-highlighting-with-solr-1-4#2850182).

Comment: So, did you manage to solve the problem? Is this response helpful?

Comment: Hey Vlad, just realized you already answered, thanks. Checking it :).